# Best way to modify a property in all elements of a nested array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, foreach, iteration

I have an object in the following format

```
const courses = [
    {
        degree: 'bsc',
        text: 'Some text',
        id: 'D001',
    }, 
    {
        degree: 'beng',
        text: 'Some text',
        id: 'D002',
    },  
    {
        degree: 'bcom',
        text: 'Some text',
        id: 'D003',
        electives: [
            {
                degree: 'bsc',
                course: 'Psychology'
                text: 'Some text',
                id: 'C010',
            },
        ],
    },
];
```

I would like to transform the `text` property of all the objects in the array, including the objects in the nested arrays, if any. This is the format I would like to get:

```
const courses = [
    {
        degree: 'bsc',
        text: translateText('D001'),
        id: 'D001',
    }, 
    {
        degree: 'beng',
        text: translateText('D002'),
        id: 'D002',
    },  
    {
        degree: 'bcom',
        text: translateText('D003'),
        id: 'D003',
        electives: [
            {
                degree: 'bsc',
                course: 'Psychology'
                text: translateText('C010'),
                id: 'C010',
            },
        ],
    },
];
```

The transformation needs to be done with the Id property passed as a parameter. This is what I have tried:

```
courses.forEach(course => {
    course.text = translateText(course.id);
    if (course.degree === 'bcom') {
        course.electives.forEach(elective => {
            elective.text = translateText(elective.id);
        })
    }
});
```

I do not like this approach since it may end up being clogged with a lot of `if` statements if arrays will be added as properties to more degree types. There may also be a performance cost (not sure if it can perform any better).

Is there a better and cleaner way of achieving the above?

Comment: Could you give me an example using Lodash, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use recursive function that will look for `electives` key and if the property exists in the object it will update the nested data structure.

```js
const courses = [{"degree":"bsc","text":"Some text","id":"D001"},{"degree":"beng","text":"Some text","id":"D002"},{"degree":"bcom","text":"Some text","id":"D003","electives":[{"degree":"bsc","course":"Psychology","text":"Some text","id":"C010"}]}]

const f = text => text + ' - updated';
const update = data => {
  data.forEach(e => {
    if (e.text) {
      e.text = f(e.text)
    }

    if (e.electives) {
      update(e.electives)
    }
  })
}

update(courses);
console.log(courses)
```

Answer (score 1):

@Nenad beat me to the recursive function, but I'm going to post this answer anyway, because you may want to recurse through *any* nested objects, not just the `electives` property. Here's how you could do that:

```js
const courses = [
    {
        degree: 'bsc',
        text: 'Some text',
        id: 'D001',
    }, 
    {
        degree: 'beng',
        text: 'Some text',
        id: 'D002',
    },  
    {
        degree: 'bcom',
        text: 'Some text',
        id: 'D003',
        electives: [
            {
                degree: 'bsc',
                course: 'Psychology'
                text: 'Some text',
                id: 'C010',
            },
        ],
    },
];

const translateTextProperty = function(obj) {
  if( typeof obj.text != 'undefined' )
    obj.text = translateText(obj.id);
  
  for(let key in obj ) {
    if( obj[key] instanceof Object ) {
      translateTextProperty( obj[key] );
    }
  }
}

courses.forEach( c => translateTextProperty(c) );
```